# Method that appends to a Stringbuilder based on user entered value

Tags: java

I have a homework problem that wants me to take a phone number and if the phone number has characters to determine what number that is. When I run my current method it returns the numbers but any characters input the method ignores them.

I have tried different versions of my current method.

```
class Telephone {

    String telephoneNumber;
    StringBuilder telephone = new StringBuilder();

    public String translator(String telephoneNumber){
        for(int i=0; i<telephoneNumber.length(); i++){
            if(Character.isDigit(telephoneNumber.charAt(i))){
                telephone.append(telephoneNumber.charAt(i));
            } else if(telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'A' || telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'B' ||  telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'C') {
                telephone.append(2);
            } else if(telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'D' || telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'E' ||  telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'F'){
                telephone.append(3);
            } else if(telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'G' || telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'H' ||  telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'I'){
                telephone.append(4);
            } else if(telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'J' || telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'K' ||  telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'L'){
                telephone.append(5);
            } else if(telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'M' || telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'N' ||  telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'O'){
                telephone.append(6);
            } else if(telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'P' || telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'Q' ||  telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'R'){
                telephone.append(7);
            } else if(telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'T' || telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'U' ||  telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'V'){
                telephone.append(8);
            } else if(telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'W' || telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'X' ||  telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'Y' ||  telephoneNumber.charAt(i) == 'Z' ){
                telephone.append(9);
            }
        }
        return telephone.toString();
    }
}
```

Current results: telephone entered `555555food` returns `555555`. I would need it to return `555 555 3662`

Comment: and ..; why? I'm sorry but I don't immediately see your logic represented in your code.

Comment: `555555food` contains lowercase `food`, but you're only checking uppercase characters. If the input is `555555FOOD` your code works as intended. So you may want to modify it to make it case-independent.

Comment: also, you may want to check your last two if statements. they are identical, so it will never reach the else of the first if

Comment: @KevinCruijssen works as intended, without the spaces in between.

Comment: @Stultuske You're correct. Also, `food`/`FOOD` should result in `3663` instead of `3662`, since the `d` becomes a `3` in OP's code..

Comment: @Ross write a function that takes in a character regardless of the case, converts it to a `String` and then check's if it `equalsIgnoreCase()` some with the character you want to check against. That should do it

Comment: @Ross wrap the characters into a String and then compare it with the stuff (convert that to String as well) you want to compare it against. That should make things smoother.

Comment: @Ross [No it doesn't..](https://tio.run/##ndXLToNAFAbgPU9x0g0QIzFqvaR20Yv12latd@NiClM6FQYyDDXG8ux1KL0b6wmzAAL/P3yHDQMyJNsD52M8tj0SRdAkjMO3BmqFcddjNkSSSHUaBswBXz01OlIw7r69AxFuZGZZyIqhCFxBfCgDp5@TW4ZZmgY6X5GkvhXE0grVBtLjxjRuSUF45BEZCKNQnKxeEDgFM1@30W7X590kPWjL82R8WOrN7lCPhv2A01bsd6mYTwbTSjVmnkPFIjcdc@XpYl6AntpbYYGVd0rATtb2tzzKXdlXBWBbW0tvSxfrGbU@EcSWKsiiOnOZNNY3sFWiIg1mmmvtdM3DFglDyp0N7dJKOQHqRTQV/NmAchn0ig6jEWzOVCeZf0I13QSEfzens45wnmKcDR3zmfdyMs8QzHMM8wLF3M/JvEQwrzDMaxSzmJPZRDBbGGYbxTzIybxBMG8xzDsU8zAn8x7BfMAwH1HMo5zMJwTzGcN8wYRedcAMc7w@jPb7SlAZC77UlUH2U5n9TRItGY9/AA)

Comment: As for an optimization in general: `for(char ch : telephoneNumber.toCharArray()){` instead of `for(int i=0; i<telephoneNumber.length(); i++)`, so you can use `ch` instead of `telephoneNumber.charAt(i)` and the code becomes a bit more compact and therefore more readable. (Or you could keep the loop as is, but create a variable for `telephoneNumber.charAt(i)`.)

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal turning it into a char, turning it back into a String ... if you just take the current method (as is) and as a first line you add telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber.toUpperCase(); you'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that takes in two `chars`, converts them to Strings using `String.valueOf()` then compare them using `equalsIgnoreCase()`. And then use that function in all of your `else-if` conditions. That should make it cleaner.

**EDIT**
You can also convert the `telephoneNumber` to upper case (or lower case, your wish) and then proceed as you were as suggested by @Stultuske in the comments

Comment: this makes little sense, and threatens to overcomplicate things a lot. What exactly is your point with this answer?

Comment: @Stultuske absolutely right, I guess I got tunnel visioned. That's the best solution what you proposed in reply to my comments. Thanks.